# Executar várias animações em sequência em jQuery sem poluir o código

Tags: jquery

Preciso que, quando uma animação termine no jQuery, outra começe. E isso deve ser feito na sequência (sem executar ao mesmo tempo).

Vi em um projeto onde trabalho um código que faz isso, mas creio que ele tenha muitos callbacks.

```js
var speed = 1000;
var cb = undefined;
$(function() {
  $('.item:eq(0)').animate({
    opacity: 1
  }, speed, function() {
    $('.item:eq(1)').animate({
      opacity: 1
    }, speed, function() {
      $('.item:eq(2)').animate({
        opacity: 1
      }, speed, function() {
        $('.item:eq(0)').animate({
          opacity: 0
        }, speed, function() {
          $('.item:eq(1)').animate({
            opacity: 0
          }, speed, function() {
            $('.item:eq(2)').animate({
              opacity: 0
            }, speed, function() {
              $.isFunction(cb) && cb();
            })
          })
        })
      })
    })
  })
});
```

```css
.item {
  height: 30px;
  background: red;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="item">item</li>
  <li class="item">item</li>
  <li class="item">item</li>
</ul>
```

Nesse caso, se tivéssemos mais de 3 itens (suponhamos que tivéssemos 20), eu não gostaria de ter que colocar 20 callbacks.

As perguntas são:

- Como poderia melhora esse código?
- Como posso fazer essas animações sequenciais em jQuery (uma esperando a outra)?

Comment: Neste exemplo específico que deste eu faria assim: http://jsfiddle.net/whoc1tpd/ -> é isso que procuras?

Comment: Pode responder assim, que você ganha +1. Isso mesmo que preciso

Answer (score 2):

Você está procurando pelo [promise](https://api.jquery.com/promise/) ;).

E o seu problema tem um nome bem conhecido, chama-se de [Callback Hell](http://callbackhell.com/)

Comment: Nunca tinha ouvido falar desse `promise`. Muito bom!

Comment: Dherik, essa resposta fica "resposta" quando colocares um exemplo de como usar promises neste caso. Ainda que ache desnecessário aqui, vou dar `+1` se [edit] a resposta com um exemplo. Se não acho que esta resposta é um comentário e não uma resposta. :)

Comment: @Sergio, pretendo fazer isto depois, agora não poderei. Mas creio que também seja uma resposta. Ela só não é tão completa como uma resposta com o código dele funcionando com `promise`. Creio que provavelmente alguém vai fazer isto antes de mim :)

Comment: @Dherik completa então quando puderes. Ainda há poucas respostas a falar de promises e acho que seria interessante. Assim como está cai na categoria de "resposta só por link" e é invalida para o site. Vou ver aqui mais logo, até breve!

Comment: @Sergio você está correto. Farei ainda hoje :).

Comment: @Dherik, estou aqui pra te lembrar que o sergio falou pra você editar a resposta :)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, pior que eu cheguei em casa, esbocei o código, mas não deu tempo de terminar. Aí esqueci...

Answer (score 1):

Nesse caso específico podes fazer isso sem jQuery até. Se percebo bem queres ir correndo os elementos, mostrando-os, e depois correr novamente escondendo. Assim sucessivamente.  Então seria algo assim:

CSS:

```
.item {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .8s;
}
.mostrar {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

JavaScript

```
(function () {
    var speed = 1000;
    var items = document.querySelectorAll('ul li');
    var index = 0;

    function iterar() {
        setTimeout(iterar, speed);
        items[index].classList.toggle('mostrar');
        index++;
        if (index == items.length) index = 0;
    }
    iterar();
})();
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/whoc1tpd/

Usando o `classList.toggle` que é nativo podes adicionar/remover uma classe num elemento. Assim criei uma função `iterar` que se vai chamando a sí própria e percorrendo os elementos para lhe dar ou remover essa classe.

Answer (score 1):

Segue um exemplo de como resolver:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
        .item {
            height: 30px;
            background: red;
            opacity: 0;
          }
    </style> 
</head>
<body>    
   
    <ul>
      <li class="item">item</li>
      <li class="item">item</li>
      <li class="item">item</li>
    </ul>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    
    function abrir(i){
        if(i == 3){ // QUANTOS ELEMENTOS IRÁ CRIAR ?
            fechar(0);
        }
        else{
            console.log(i);            
            $('.item:eq('+i+')').animate({ opacity: 1 }, 1000, function() { 
                i = i + 1;
                abrir(i); 
            });            
        }        
    };
    
    function fechar(i){
        if(i == 3){ // QUANTOS ELEMENTOS IRÁ CRIAR ?
            return 0; 
        }
        else{
            console.log(i);            
            $('.item:eq('+i+')').animate({ opacity: 0 }, 1000, function() { 
                i = i + 1;
                fechar(i); 
            });            
        }
    };
    
    $(function() {
        abrir(0);                
    });
</script>  
</html>
```

Comment: Amigo, não consigo dar +1 hoje :( . Mas não vou esquecer de dar o merecido +1